# Feasibility of PowerPoint (Cooporate Design)

Tags: office365, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

Our marketing colleagues are working to improve an internal workflow to use the correct PowerPoint template (corporate design templates).

The main problem is that the employees tend to copy and modify old presentations rather than use the newest template.

Is there an opportunity that informs employees of the correct use of the corporate design with a visual message, hint or popup?

Is there a way or solution to influence on Microsoft products to 
ensure the use of coorporate templates with PowerPoint?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about people and processes

Comment: It maybe about people and processes, but it is also a technical issue for that I need a solution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

It would possible to verify that an opened file has the correct template IF the user has an add-in installed in their copy of PowerPoint to do this.

Comment: That's exactly what I imagined. Thanks for the answer.
Can you recommend a link to me, which is explained in detail?

Comment: I don't know of any specific link. Basically, an installed add-in would have to look at the template of the current presentation and work out whether it's the correct one. For example, it might look for a uniquely named shape one of the slide masters or layouts.

Comment: regarding to this installed add-in. Is there a ready-made solution, or does this add-in need to be developed first ? Thank you again.

Comment: This would need to be an add-in developed specifically for this purpose. It's not something you'd be able to purchase "off-the-shelf".  I've done several similar add-ins for corporate clients and would be happy to discuss this with you via email if you wish.  You can visit my site, www.pptools.com and use the contact link on every page to get in touch.

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks for offering. ok. First i'm checking our vendor policies and then will contact you. Can you give me an imagine, how much does this take time to develop, test and deliver an addin ?

Comment: We can discuss that via email, Sarah.  Thanks.